# como hacer que un boton modifique un textview en un fragment

Tags: android-studio

Tengo 3 botones en un `fragment` y quiero que cada uno de ellos ponga un texto diferente en un `textview` que esta en el mismo `fragment`.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 1):

Tu debes de tener en cuanta que cada `fragment` esta ligado con un `layout` por lo tanto si necesitas generar acciones con tus botones primero tienes que cargar la interfaz del `fragment` y de ahí ya puedes hacer lo de los botones. Deberías de tener algo similar a esto.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView tv_nombre;
    Button btn_uno, btn_dos, btn_tres;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Cargas la vista 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nombre_del_layout_del_fragment, container, false);
        // A partir de la vista mandas a traer los botones correspondientes.
        tv_nombre = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre);
        btn_uno = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_uno);
        btn_dos = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_dos);
        btn_tres = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_tres);
        //Esta lógica se replica para los demas botones.
        btn_uno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Cambias el contenido del TextView
                tv_nombre.setText("Hola mundo, boton 1");
            }
        });
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que se más específico en su pregunta y luego procedemos a responder. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.